# Multiple input in python

Tags: python, input, gmail

So I've written this piece of code which sends a message that I type in an input field. The problem is that I want to be able to type multiple lines in the input field. The code is SUPPOSED to type multiple lines, but instead just sends the last line to my email.

Here is my code:

```
# modules
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage


ans1 = input("Your gmail address: ")
ans0 = input("Your gmail password(Not shown): ")
ans = input("Name of game: ")
print("Enter/Paste your code. Ctrl-D to send it.")
contents = []
while True:
    try:
        line = input()
    except EOFError:
        break
    contents.append(line)

# content
sender = ans1
reciever = "rockzombie005@gmail.com"
password = ans0
msg_body = line


# action
msg = EmailMessage()
msg['subject'] = ans   
msg['from'] = sender
msg['to'] = reciever
msg.set_content(msg_body)

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
    smtp.login(sender,password)
        
    smtp.send_message(msg)

print("Program sent successfully!")
```

When I run my code, it sends me the last line only:

CODE OUTPUT

```
Your gmail address: *******@gmail.com
Your gmail password(Not shown): ********
Name of game: GAME
Enter/Paste your code. Ctrl-D to send it.
Line 1
Line 2 (end)
Program sent successfully!
```

GMAIL:

```
Line 2 (end)
```

Comment: You're sending `line`, not `contents`. `line` contains the last line, `contents` is a list of all lines.

Comment: In your own words, where you do `msg_body = line`, what do you think will be the result? In your own words, what is the purpose of `contents` in your code? Do you see anything in your code that *uses* that value, after it has been prepared?

Comment: @Barmar this is obviously a typo, why not close the question instead?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel If it were just the wrong variable I would have. But since it also requires joining to convert the list to a string, I felt it was substantial enough for an answer.

Comment: Hmm, fair enough.

Comment: Barmar's answer solved my problem and my question was specific enough, so I feel like there is no use of closing this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending only the last line with

```
msg_body = line
```

You need to send all the lines in `contents`.

```
msg_body = "\n".join(contents)
```